# Making the api call in background on button click and moving to another view immediately

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a save button and when I click on it, I want to make an api call and move to another view. Since the api call is taking a while to complete, I would like to move to the next view as soon as I click the button and make the api call in the background. I am not able to achieve this. Here is the  code in my button touchupinside event:

```
InvokeInBackground(MakeApiCall);
var storyBoard = UIStoryboard.FromName("Main", NSBundle.MainBundle);
MainTabBarController viewController = storyBoard.InstantiateViewController("MainTabBarController") as MainTabBarController;
PresentViewController(viewController, true, null);
```

Comment: Where does `InvokeInBackground` live and what does it do?

Answer (score 2):

Use the Grand Central Dispatch (`GCD`) place an `Action` on the background queue/thread:

```
DispatchQueue.GetGlobalQueue(DispatchQueuePriority.Background).DispatchAsync(() =>
{
    SomeFunctionToRunOnQueue();
});
```

#### Example:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();

    button = new UIButton(new CGRect(50, 50, 200, 50))
    {
        BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red
    };
    button.SetTitle("Background", UIControlState.Normal);
    Add(button);
    button.TouchUpInside += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Current Thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
        DispatchQueue.GetGlobalQueue(DispatchQueuePriority.Background).DispatchAsync(() =>
        {
            DoWork();
        });
    };
}

public async void DoWork()
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Current Thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");

    // Do some work...
    await Task.Delay(2000);

    // Go back to the UI thread to do some display updates
    DispatchQueue.MainQueue.DispatchAsync(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Current Thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
        button.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green;
    });
}
```